# In Grails, how do I mock GrailsDomainBinder in a unit test?

Tags: grails, discriminator, grails-2.0.4

I have a bunch of subclasses like so:

```
abstract class Fruit {
    ...

    String getType() {
        // get the discriminator value for this type
        GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(this.class).discriminator
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    static mapping = {
        discriminator 'Apple'
    }
}

class Pear extends Fruit {
    static mapping = {
        discriminator 'Pear'
    }
}
```

In other words, `Fruit` is a base type with `Apple` and `Pear` as subtypes. I exposed a `type` property that gets the discriminator value that's set in the subclasses.

Now I have a `JsonExportService` that exports an instance as JSON data. When I'm running the application, this service correctly exports the `type` property filled in with the discriminator value.

I now need to write a unit test for `JsonExportService`. Problem is, `GrailsDomainBinder` doesn't seem to be mocked out in unit tests, and I'm getting NPE: cannot access `discriminator` property on a null object.

I can work around it in two ways:

1. Create a static property in each subclass that has the same value as the discriminator:

   ```
   class Pear extends Fruit {
       static String type = 'Pear'
       ...
   }
   ```

   This seems really hacky though, and I'm declaring the same value in two places.
2. Change the `getType()` code to:

   ```
   GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(this.class)?.discriminator
   ```

   This works, but now I'm basically ignoring the discriminator altogether, and the unit test is not 'complete' because it requires a follow-up integration test to ensure that the `getType()` method is returning the correct value.

Does anyone know of a better, unit-testing-friendly way of getting the discriminator value from the domain mapping?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `DefaultGrailsDomainConfiguration` is the responsible to initializing the mappings, so you can try:

```
def domainClass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(Pear.class.name)
DefaultGrailsDomainConfiguration.configureDomainBinder(grailsApplication, [domainClass] as Set)
println GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(Pear)
```